# Android listview onClick doesn't work

Tags: android, android-listview

When I use notifyDataSetChanged on listview, onClick listener responds only a couple of times . after that, onClick listener doesn't work.

I guess when listitem is notifyDataSetChanged, some chaches would remain.

Please tell me how to fix it.

codes below:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        holder.mIconImg = customFindViewById(convertView, R.id.icon_img);
        holder.mTitleText = customFindViewById(convertView, R.id.item_title_text);
        holder.mDescText = customFindViewById(convertView, R.id.item_descr_text);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    HashMap<IField, Object> item = getItem(position);
    String imageUrl = getHashmap(item, ItemField.ICON_URL);
    Drawable image = ImageCache.getImage(imageUrl);
    if (image == null) {
        ImageDownloadTask task = new ImageDownloadTask(holder.mIconImg, null, null);

        holder.mIconImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.error_ic);

        try {
            task.execute(Utility.getHashmap(item, ItemField.ICON_URL));
        } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        holder.mIconImg.setImageDrawable(image);

    }
    String title = getHashmap(item, ItemField.CATEGORY_LIST_TEXT);
    holder.mTitleText.setText(title);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mItemList.get(position);

    // convertView.getFocusables(position);
    // convertView.clearFocus();
    convertView.setEnabled(true);
    return convertView;

}
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a clickListener in this code... Either you need to re-word your question a bit more clearly or you've posted code that doesn't seem to be terribly relevant.

Comment: As already mentioned your code has nothing to do with a clickListener. You just show how you populate each row of your listview

Comment: Also, usually setOnItemClickListener is used instead of setOnClickListener when dealing with ListViews.

Comment: I use setOnItemClickListener on other class. it works well before scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be calling `this.notifyDataSetChanged()` in your `getView()` method. It's also probably not doing anything useful.

Comment: Thank you for that. setOnItemClickListener are getting work very well.

Comment: but icon image on list view is frequently switching on other icon image many times.

Comment: Wait, do you mean that the image doesn't update when it's downloaded? Then your design is wrong. You need a "notifier" mechanism that will let you know when the image has been downloaded,  which then updates the `ImageView`. It doesn't make sense *at all* to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` because the dataset has not actually changed.